# Etcd failing to setup cluster due to failure to find etcd local member

Tags: dns, bind, etcd, etcd3

I'm attempting to setup a cluster on Ubuntu 18.04 host machines. I'm getting the following error when using DNS for server discovery.

`error setting up initial cluster: cannot find local etcd member "etcd-1" in SRV records`

I've followed the docs and feel like I've done it all correctly, but I'm new to setting up a local dns (using bind9) and can't tell what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried altering my dns around but have not been able to solve the problem. The issue is only happening when trying to discover the local node...

Here's the SRV records for the _etcd-server

```
user@etcd-1:~$ dig +noall +answer SRV _etcd-server._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com
_etcd-server._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com.    9 IN SRV 0 0 2380 etcd-2.etcd.abc-bird.com.
_etcd-server._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com.    9 IN SRV 0 0 2380 etcd-3.etcd.abc-bird.com.
_etcd-server._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com.    9 IN SRV 0 0 2380 etcd-1.etcd.abc-bird.com.
```

My SRV records for _etcd-client-ssl

```
user@etcd-1:~$ dig +noall +answer SRV _etcd-client-ssl._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com
_etcd-client-ssl._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com. 60 IN SRV 0 0 2379 etcd-2.etcd.abc-bird.com.
_etcd-client-ssl._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com. 60 IN SRV 0 0 2379 etcd-1.etcd.abc-bird.com.
_etcd-client-ssl._tcp.etcd.abc-bird.com. 60 IN SRV 0 0 2379 etcd-3.etcd.abc-bird.com.
```

My A records

```
user@etcd-1:~$ dig +noall +answer etcd-1.etcd.abc-bird.com. etcd-2.etcd.abc-bird.com. etcd-3.etcd.abc-bird.com.
etcd-1.etcd.abc-bird.com. 35    IN  A   192.168.0.28
etcd-2.etcd.abc-bird.com. 35    IN  A   192.168.0.20
etcd-3.etcd.abc-bird.com. 35    IN  A   192.168.0.29
```

here's my etcd.service file contents

```
[Unit]
Description=ETCD  Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=etcd
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd --data-dir=/opt/etcd/data --name=${hostname} \
  --discovery-srv etcd.${domain} \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://${hostname}.etcd.${domain}:2380 \
  --listen-peer-urls=https://0.0.0.0:2380 \
  --listen-client-urls=https://0.0.0.0:2379 \
  --peer-cert-allowed-cn=etcd.${domain} \
  --advertise-client-urls=https://${hostname}.etcd.${domain}:2379 \
  --initial-cluster-token=etcd-cluster-1 \
  --initial-cluster-state=new \
  --client-cert-auth --trusted-ca-file=/opt/etcd/ca.pem \
  --cert-file=/opt/etcd/cert.pem --key-file=/opt/etcd/key.pem \
  --peer-client-cert-auth --peer-trusted-ca-file=/opt/etcd/ca.pem \
  --peer-cert-file=/opt/etcd/cert.pem --peer-key-file=/opt/etcd/key.pem
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The journalctl logs containing the error

```
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 systemd[1]: Started ETCD  Service.
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: etcd Version: 3.3.12
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: Git SHA: d57e8b8
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: Go Version: go1.10.8
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: setting maximum number of CPUs to 2, total number of available CPUs is 2
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: peerTLS: cert = /opt/etcd/cert.pem, key = /opt/etcd/key.pem, ca = , trusted-ca = /opt/etcd/ca.pem, client-cert-auth = true, crl-file =
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: listening for peers on https://0.0.0.0:2380
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: listening for client requests on 0.0.0.0:2379
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 0=http://etcd-2.etcd.abc-bird.com:2380
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 1=http://etcd-3.etcd.abc-bird.com:2380
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 etcd[6918]: error setting up initial cluster: cannot find local etcd member "etcd-1" in SRV records
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 systemd[1]: etcd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 14 15:23:37 etcd-1 systemd[1]: etcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 14 15:23:42 etcd-1 systemd[1]: etcd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
```

For what it's worth, here is my dns config on my name server.
https://gist.github.com/spstratis/1e89f867d86c6b37dc15387ccd310fcc